# Are there other/better voxel meshing algorithm than Greddy Meshing

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh

For the project I'm working, I have large voxel data I need to visualize within a mesh.

While searching I rapidly find the [Meshing in a Minecraft Game article](https://0fps.net/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/) article, written by mikolalysenko back in 2012, and according to my research seems to only source everyone is referring to answer this question.
He describes three algorithm to solving this problem: the Stupid, the Culled and the Greedy.

The two first are really non efficient, so I made a Python version of the code he provides for my project with two tweaks:

- I use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up computations
- I directly compute the triangle vertices instead of quadrilaterals, to mach to our meshing function implementation

```py
@njit()
def greedy_mesh(volume, dims):
    def f(i, j, k):
        return(volume[i + dims[0] * (j + dims[1] * k)])
    
    points = []
    # Sweep over 3-axes
    for d in range(3):
        u = (d + 1) % 3
        v = (d + 2) % 3
        x = [0, 0, 0]
        q = [0, 0, 0]
        mask = [0] * (dims[u] * dims[v])
        
        q[d] = 1
        
        x[d] = -1
        while x[d] < dims[d]:
            n = 0
            x[v] = 0
            x[u] = 0
            # Compute mask
            while x[v] < dims[v]:
                while x[u] < dims[u]:
                    a = f(x[0], x[1], x[2]) if x[d] >= 0 else False
                    b = f(x[0] + q[0], x[1] + q[1], x[2] + q[2]) if x[d] < (dims[d] - 1) else False
                                   
                    mask[n] = a != b 
                    n += 1
                    
                    x[u] += 1
                
                x[u] = 0
                x[v] += 1
            
            x[d] += 1
            
            n = 0
            # Generate mesh for mask using lexicographic ordering
            for j in range(0, dims[v]):
                i = 0
                while i < dims[u]:                        
                    if (n < len(mask)) and mask[n]:
                        w = 1
                        # Compute width
                        while (n + w < len(mask)) and (mask[n + w] and ((i + w) < dims[u])):
                            w += 1
                        
                        done = False
                        h = 1
                        # Compute height (slighty awkward according to the autor)
                        while (j + h) < dims[v]:
                            for k in range(0, w):
                                if not mask[n + k + h * dims[u]]:
                                    done = True
                                    break
                                    
                            if done:
                                break
                                
                            h += 1
                        
                        # New quad
                        x[u] = i;
                        x[v] = j;
                        du = [0, 0, 0]
                        dv = [0, 0, 0]
                        
                        du[u] = w
                        dv[v] = h
                        
                        # Triangles
                        A = (x[0],
                             x[1],
                             x[2])
                        B = (x[0] + du[0],
                             x[1] + du[1],
                             x[2] + du[2])
                        C = (x[0] + du[0] + dv[0],
                             x[1] + du[1] + dv[1],
                             x[2] + du[2] + dv[2])
                        D = (x[0] + dv[0],
                             x[1] + dv[1],
                             x[2] + dv[2])
                        
                        points.extend([A, B, C])
                        points.extend([A, C, D])
                        
                        # Zero-out mask
                        for l in range(0, h):
                            for k in range(0, w):
                                mask[n + k + l * dims[u]] = False
                        
                        i += w
                        n += w
                        
                    else:
                        i += 1
                        n += 1

    # Unique set of points
    vertices = [i for i in set(points)]
    
    # Points 
    indices = []
    for p in points:
        indices.append(vertices.index(p))
    
    return np.array(vertices), np.array(indices).reshape(-1, 3)
```

I test out my code using the examples provides once again by mikolalysenko and it run perfectly fine.
But then I tried to load bigger voxel data from our project (~ 300x300x300), and now the algorithm run for about 5s to process the data. Honestly I quite fast but not enough for usage, and we have much larger data sets.

After a bit of profile, and without really any surprise, most of computation time is due to creation of the vertices and their indices at the end. Unfortunetly, this is the way the meshing function was created to work with and I'm not able to change this feature.

That's finally leads my to my question: Is there today a voxel meshing algorithm better than Greedy Meshing that could helps me fulfill my requirements?

Even if I believe there is no optimal solution for this kind of task (looks a bit like a P = NP problem), I cannot find alternative algorithms online even while looking for scientific papers.

Do you have any suggestions or references regarding my problem?

Comment: "large voxel data I need to visualize within a mesh": what does that mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean at some point I will need to generate a list of vertices from the voxel data, in order to be display it.
This corresponds to the end of my code where I lost most of the algorithm performance, and I cannot do without it due to the way our meshing function is built.

Comment: What vertices ? Are you after an iso-surface ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry for the confusion, I will try to be as clear as possible.
My goal is to generate a mesh from voxel data. To do so, I  need to compute the corresponding vertices coordinates in order to visualuaze my voxel the 'classic' way using triangle made for those vertices.

Comment: There is nothing to see in voxels. https://proyectoidis.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/fig2.2a.png